# How to make Ajax wait for a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have to show data for a number of clients. Unfortunately, the loading process for a group of clients is super slow. Then I've decided to load one by one and as soon as possible, in other words, when the page is rendered for the first time. Here is the current code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

// here, clients = [{'client': 1, 'loaded': false}, {'client': 2, 'loaded': false}, ...]
    
$.each(clients, function(index, value){ 
        if (!value.loaded){
            $.ajax({ url: 'loadclient',
                    data: {client: value.client},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                                value.loaded = true;
                             }
                    });
        };
     });
});
```

While clients are loading, I want to display a view of the loaded clients. Then I have a dropdown box where users can choose which client to get. The thing is: I want to show data if the selected client is loaded OR wait until the client finally get loaded and then show data. When user selects a client then I have several ajax calls to build the view. Here is an example of one of them:

```
function get_SFN(){
    $.ajax({url: 'update_sfn',
        data: {client: client},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            
            var risks = response.risks;
            var values = response.values;
            
            buildGraphSFN(risks, values) ;

        }
    });
};
```

When the user selects a client, I need to check if it is loaded. If it is not loaded, I want to wait for this condition to be true and then run the second ajax.

How can I fix this?

Comment: DON'T make http requests in a loop.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion about how to deal with this?